# How to parse random key value pair string in Python?

Tags: python, regex, parsing, key-value

what's the most efficient way to parse this string?

```
AccountSid=AC03e13571d5434152f33553f6&MessageSid=SM16bbbc0a82847e61200a59d82cc1732b&Body=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DZtWUF1MmaMA%26feature%3Dyoutube_gdata_player&ToZip=92707&ToCity=GARDEN+GROVE&FromState=CA&ToState=CA&SmsSid=SM16bbbc0a82847e61200a59d82cc1732b&To=%2B17147866508&ToCountry=US&FromCountry=US&SmsMessageSid=SM16bbbc0a82847e61200a59d82cc1732b&ApiVersion=2010-04-01&FromCity=SANTA+ANA&SmsStatus=received&NumMedia=0&From=%2B17145420218&FromZip=92704
```

Comment: `urlparse` is module u r looking for.

Comment: efficient? & what inefficient ways have you tried?

Comment: The most efficient way is to write a parser in assembly and a tiny extension module in C that uses it. Have fun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`urlparse.parse_qs()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs) to parse URL-encoded key-value pairs.

Demo:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> inputstr = 'AccountSid=AC03e13571d5434152f33553f6&MessageSid=SM16bbbc0a82847e61200a59d82cc1732b&Body=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DZtWUF1MmaMA%26feature%3Dyoutube_gdata_player&ToZip=92707&ToCity=GARDEN+GROVE&FromState=CA&ToState=CA&SmsSid=SM16bbbc0a82847e61200a59d82cc1732b&To=%2B17147866508&ToCountry=US&FromCountry=US&SmsMessageSid=SM16bbbc0a82847e61200a59d82cc1732b&ApiVersion=2010-04-01&FromCity=SANTA+ANA&SmsStatus=received&NumMedia=0&From=%2B17145420218&FromZip=92704'
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(urlparse.parse_qs(inputstr))
{'AccountSid': ['AC03e13571d5434152f33553f6'],
 'ApiVersion': ['2010-04-01'],
 'Body': ['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZtWUF1MmaMA&feature=youtube_gdata_player'],
 'From': ['+17145420218'],
 'FromCity': ['SANTA ANA'],
 'FromCountry': ['US'],
 'FromState': ['CA'],
 'FromZip': ['92704'],
 'MessageSid': ['SM16bbbc0a82847e61200a59d82cc1732b'],
 'NumMedia': ['0'],
 'SmsMessageSid': ['SM16bbbc0a82847e61200a59d82cc1732b'],
 'SmsSid': ['SM16bbbc0a82847e61200a59d82cc1732b'],
 'SmsStatus': ['received'],
 'To': ['+17147866508'],
 'ToCity': ['GARDEN GROVE'],
 'ToCountry': ['US'],
 'ToState': ['CA'],
 'ToZip': ['92707']}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`urlparse.parse_qs`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs):

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> s = "AccountSid=AC03e13555434152f33553f6&MessageSid=SM16bbbc0a82847e61200a59d82cc1732b&Body=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DZtWUF1MmaMA%26feature%3Dyoutube_gdata_player&ToZip=92707&ToCity=GARDEN+GROVE&FromState=CA&ToState=CA&SmsSid=SM16bbbc0a82847e61200a59d82cc1732b&To=%2B17147866508&ToCountry=US&FromCountry=US&SmsMessageSid=SM16bbbc0a82847e61200a59d82cc1732b&ApiVersion=2010-04-01&FromCity=SANTA+ANA&SmsStatus=received&NumMedia=0&From=%2B17145420218&FromZip=92704"
>>> urlparse.parse_qs(s)
{'Body': ['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZtWUF1MmaMA&feature=youtube_gdata_player'], 'MessageSid': ['SM16bbbc0a82847e61200a59d82cc1732b'], 'FromZip': ['92704'], 'SmsStatus': ['received'], 'FromCountry': ['US'], 'FromCity': ['SANTA ANA'], 'ApiVersion': ['2010-04-01'], 'To': ['+17147866508'], 'From': ['+17145420218'], 'NumMedia': ['0'], 'ToZip': ['92707'], 'ToCountry': ['US'], 'ToState': ['CA'], 'AccountSid': ['AC03e13571dbc3a33555434152f33553f6'], 'SmsSid': ['SM16bbbc0a82847e61200a59d82cc1732b'], 'ToCity': ['GARDEN GROVE'], 'FromState': ['CA'], 'SmsMessageSid': ['SM16bbbc0a82847e61200a59d82cc1732b']}
```